# I'm updating User data in mongoDB via "PATCH" request, its working with POSTMAN but not updating data via HTML

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, rest, ejs

I've used same route for both GET and PATCH request i.e, "/user/:userId"

Backend Code:

```
app.route("/user/:userId")
.get = ((req, res) => {
  User.findById(req.params.userId).then((user) => {
    res.render("user", {
      username: user.username,
      userType: user.userType,
      userId: req.params.userId,
    });
  });
}).patch = (req, res) => {
  User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.userId, req.body)
};
```

HTML Code:

```
  <body>
    <h1>User</h1>
    <form action="/user/<%= userId %>" method="PATCH">
      <label for="username">Username:</label>
      <input type="text" name="username" value="<%= username %>" />
      <br />
      <label for="userType">User Type:</label>
      <input type="text" name="userType" value="<%= userType %>" />
      <br />
      <button type="submit">Update</button>
    </form>   </body>
```

As I submit my form, there is no Error but it doesn't update the user data in my mongoDB database.

But if I use POSTMAN, it is working fine without any problems.

Comment: it should be http://localhost:5000/user/648c74c294007fad94279197 not http://localhost:5000/user/:648c74c294007fad94279197

Comment: @SuleymanSah when I log the value of req.params.userId then it gives "648c74c294007fad94279197" not ":648c74c294007fad94279197" and I use "/user/<%= userId %>" in the html form

Comment: @SuleymanSah : the above error was due to the following line 
      res.redirect(`/user/:${req.params.userId}`);
So now I have changed the code as the following and it is working fine:
      res.redirect(`/user/${req.params.userId}`);